# Free tool that fills transparent areas in a picture in a content aware way

Tags: image-processing

Photoshop seems to have a feature to automatically fill transparent areas in a photo in a content-aware way with machine learning where the machine learning guesses the best way to replace the transparent area.

Given that photoshop licenses are quite costly I want a free tool that automatically does the work for me. Is there free tool that does this for me?

Answer (score 1):

A free alternative to Photoshop is Gimp - And as soon as you want to perform or apply a set of manipulations to an entire group of images, it is worth using BIMP.

Users can make changes such as zooming, cropping, rotating, adjusting color, or applying various effects to any number of images. It is possible to include other plugins or self-written events in this process.

https://www.alessandrofrancesconi.it/projects/bimp/

Or you could also use Gimps Batch Mode on the command-line:

https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/

Comment: I know that Gimp exists but I'm not aware how to do this task well with Gimp. The amount that the Photoshop team invested into machine learning isn't matched by Gimp. If there's a plugin for gimp that does this task, can you point to it?

Comment: Have you looked at Bimp?
Unfortunately, I can't think of a better free tool.
I am a graphic artist and work a lot with Photoshop. Gimp definitely can't get to usability, but I often have to work with Gimp (employers with Linux machines only) - and it works. With Bimp you can apply a series of Gimp manipulations to a group of images.

Comment: What about [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), can it be used for such operations as asked by the OP? I only ask since you're the graphic expert and I've used it for image batch operations from command line or scripts but thought I'd throw that out there in case you know of a method. It sounds like the BIMP plugin should do though.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT With Image Magick I have only performed very simple batch operations so far. But if it's just about filling the transparent background, for example, that shouldn't be a problem.

Replacing whole colors (or similar color like green screens) should also work with the fuzzy selectors from Image Magick.

However, I think that Gimp and Bimp should be much easier for people with no console experience.